# How to replace out of control nested conditions within an if statement

Tags: asp.net

Basically we have quite a few fields within our member search.

We have a few optimized store procedures specifically for certain searches. For example if the user only searches by email address then it would use SearchMemberEmail however if it's search by postcode only then it would use SearchMemberPostcode.

This is all to do with the execution plan in sql server am told.

So we have a LONG ass if statement that basically checks if the the other text boxes are empty. i.e.

```
   if(!string.isnullorempty(Email.Text) && string.isnullorempty(a.Text) && string.isnullorempty(b.Text)
{
   Use SearMemberByemail stored procedure
}
```

The if statement is horrible and hard to read is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Have you considered using a [`RequiredFieldValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx)?

Comment: No no it's not a required field it's a optional. You can search by email only or you can search by postcode.

Comment: Is it only one field at a time or you can enter into multiple fields

Comment: It's either you can search by just email OR you can do a combination of surname and firstname for example in which case it uses a generic stored procedure without execution plan caching

Comment: `if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailField))
       proc = "SearMemberByemail";
    else if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastname))
       proc = "SearchFirstNameLastName";
    else
       throw new Exception("Enter email or firstname and lastname");
`

Comment: Re: "to do with the execution plan in sql server" - you should check that the parameters specify the size of the parameter, otherwise a separate execution plan is generated for each submitted size of the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the string.IsNullOrEmpty values to get one number which you can then act on. I only did this as a crude Windows Forms program which displays the intended action in a Label, but it shows the principle:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int choices = ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(uEmail.Text)) ? 0 : 1) +
        ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(uA.Text)) ? 0 : 2) +
        ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(uB.Text)) ? 0 : 4);
    switch (choices)
    {
        case 1:
            // search for email
            label1.Text = "Email search";
            break;
        case 2:
            // search for A
            label1.Text = "A search";
           break;
        case 4:
            // search for B
            label1.Text = "B search";
            break;
        case 6:
            // search for A+B
            label1.Text = "A+B search";
            break;
        default:
            // general search
            label1.Text = "General search";
            break;
    }

}
```

Further options would use values of 8, 16, 32...

Comment: Thank you Andrew!!! You're my savior!! Hopefully eventually I will be able to approach a problem from different angle!

Comment: So double the number each time basically.

Comment: @Ageis Yes: it is setting individual bits in `choices`. Some people might prefer to use `|` instead of `+` to combine the values.